# how to print the \sectionautorefname with autoref, but without hyper-linking the \sectionautorefname?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, autoref

EDIT: @Faekynn and @Mico you are right that the starred version disable the hyperlinkification, but is it possible to disable it only for the `\sectionautorefname`, but still keep it for the `section number` ?

==============================

how to have  the feature of `autoref`, that is to say printing the `sectionautorefname+ section number` but without a hyper-link for the `sectionautorefname`.

It must work for the other sectionning units.

Comment: What about `\autoref*`?

Comment: You may want to look into the capabilities of the `cleveref` package. Its cross-referencing macros are far more customizable than those of the `hyperref` package.

Answer (score 3):

If the `hyperref` package is loaded, use the "starred" versions of various cross-referencing macros -- `\autoref*`, `\ref*`, etc. -- if you don't want to create hyperlinks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{First}  \label{sec:first}
\subsection{abc} \label{subsec:abc}
\subsection{xyz} \label{subsec:xyz}

As argued in \autoref{subsec:abc}, \dots  % hyperlink is created

\medskip\noindent
As argued in \autoref*{subsec:xyz}, \dots % hyperlink is not created
\end{document}
```